# Amazon lambda java.lang.VerifyError for JSON input strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have my build.sbt as

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "lambda-demo",
    version := "1.0",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.4",
    retrieveManaged := true,
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.7.2",
    libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.7.2"
  )

mergeStrategy in assembly :=
  {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }
```

And I got this error on testing my AWS Lambda function

```
{
  "errorMessage": "class com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.ser.ScalaIteratorSerializer overrides final method withResolved.(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanProperty;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeSerializer;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/AsArraySerializerBase;",
  "errorType": "java.lang.VerifyError"
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" library dependency to version 2.10 solves the problem.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.10" % "2.7.2"
```

Comment: This is incorrect, that only changes the scala version of the jackson-module. In this case it should be `jackson-module-scala_2.11` because the scala version is `2.11.x`